# Returning the count of specific consecutive items

Tags: python, function

I have a the following list, my_list = ['UK', 'FR', 'UK','SP', 'CN', 'USA', 'UK'] and I'm trying to return the maximum consecutive items which is not followed by the 'UK'.

So for example, the max consecutive items would be 3 here ('SP', 'CN', 'USA')

I have started the following but this only returns a count without the 'UK'.

```
def country_count(my_list):
    new_country = []
    for country in my_list:
        if country != 'UK':
            new_country.append(country)
        else:
            continue
    return len(new_country)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store all the countries names. You can just count the max.

```
def country_count(my_list):
    max = 0
    count = 0
    for country in my_list:
        if country != 'UK':
            count += 1
        else:
            if count > max:
                max = count
            count = 0
    return max
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a counter to store the current number of observations and updates the max value which resets if 'UK' is found.

```
my_list = ['UK', 'FR', 'UK','SP', 'CN', 'USA', 'UK'] 

counter, max_val = 0, 0 # counter and max occurences

for idx, item in enumerate(my_list): # traverse the list
    if idx+1 != len(my_list): # if it is not the last element, check next element
        if my_list[idx+1] != 'UK': # check if following element is 'UK'
            counter += 1 # if not 'UK', increment counter
            if counter > max_val: # if current count is greater than previous max, store it
                max_val = counter
        else:
            counter = 0 # reset counter

print(max_val)
```